# Computer talks german after windows loads

Tags: windows-7

After windows starts I can hear a german speaking woman talking.

How do I find where it comes from and disable it?

It's  Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Before or after the login dialog?

Comment: @Robert no login dialog, right into desktop

Comment: I would reinstall Windows you have either Malware or enabled a feature within Windows that does this. Unless you can tell us what the voice is saying it would be hard to figure out what is going on.  My first thought was some disability feature, my second was malware, don't have advice for either.

Comment: @Ramhound well i can't understand whats saying, not german, it only happens right after windows load and not everytime.

Comment: Skynet?  Speaking German?  Uh Oh.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't change your OS localization to French!!

Answer (score 2):

Check your start-up programs and their sound/alert settings. Some, including, most ironically, antiviruses, have quite annoying voiced messages about their progress. For example Avast antivirus used to have "bases are updated" message, scaring anyone passing by if you forgot to turn off speakers.

To help narrow search, I recommend capturing sound and posting it somewhere to let German speaker actually translate what it says.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds likely that you've picked up some malware.  I had this happen about a year ago where an app I downloaded off the internet installed a background service that would cause voice advertisements to play in the background in Windows about every 10 minutes (except mine was in English).  I would try running several different anti-virus and anti-malware programs and see if any of them can pick up on it and remove it.  If not, you'll have to go through the running Services in Windows and see if you can figure out which one is the culprit.  Removing the ad-ware service isn't always easy and may require a bit of effort to stamp out all traces of it.